# Meaning of notation $\frac{1}{N}\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-geometry, notation, modular-forms

I am reading a set of notes (on modular curves: [here)](http://swc.math.arizona.edu/aws/2001/01Weston1.pdf), which seems to suggest on page 5 that  $\frac{1}{11}\mathbb{Z}$ is a cyclic group of order 11. Am I missing something? Doesn't this notation just mean the integers multiplied by $11$, which certainly doesn't have order 11?

Comment: If it says that it is a cyclic group of order $11$, then that's what it is. I think this is more often written as ${\mathbb Z}/11$, which is an abbreviation of ${\mathbb Z}/11{\mathbb Z}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is of course the rational numbers whose denominator is $11$.  Its image in the **complex torus** $\Bbb{C/(Z+\tau Z)}$ is a cyclic subgroup with $11$ elements.

Comment: I am confused by the notation in the paper then. It says a modular pair is of the form $(\mathbb{C}/\Lambda, C)$, where $C$ is a cyclic group of order $11$. Is this incorrect?

Comment: A cyclic subgroup of the complex torus (this is for the points of $X_0(11)$, for $X_1(11)$ it is a single point of order $11$)